# Angular 4 Firebase Read data from database and display to browser

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am learning Angular 4 and I am using firebase database.But I am completly lost on how I can make the objects apear on the browser of my application.
I currently want to take all the data from users and display them on the browser.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-about',
  templateUrl: './about.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./about.component.css']
})
export class AboutComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {
    var allUsers = firebase.database().ref('users/');
      var db = firebase.database().ref('/users/');
      // Attach an asynchronous callback to read the data at our posts reference
        db.on("value", function(snapshot) {
          console.log(snapshot.val());
        }, function (errorObject) {
          console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
        });
          }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Everything works fine and I can see my data on the console.But can you help me on how I can make the data on the console apear on the browser??

Comment: What do you have in about.component.html?

Comment: Nothing yet.. I got no idea how i am suppose to make the data apear on browser..

Comment: You should create the data model in your class and bind it to the view (html).

Comment: Yes yes I know this but where I find the code which displays the data from my database on the Browser?? I mean if it was php I would use                
      `<?= row['something'] ?>` on html tag.. but now I completly lost on how to display data from database on browser..

Comment: The official tuto is good to learn the basics of Angular :) https://angular.io/tutorial

Comment: Well thanks a lot.. I will try to find more help on the tutorial then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well there is no need to use console.log() if you want to display data on Browser.Angularfire has its own functions for this.
[This link focus exactly on your problem](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/3-retrieving-data-as-lists.md)

Here is an example that takes all the users name from a database and displays them as a list

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable,FirebaseObjectObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-about',
  templateUrl: './about.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./about.component.css']
})
export class AboutComponent implements OnInit {

    users:FirebaseListObservable<any>;;
    constructor(db2: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.users = db2.list('users');
          }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
```

And the following Html code

```
<div class="container">
  <p>Show all users</p>
  <ul>
  <li *ngFor="let user of users | async">
       {{ user.name | json }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Hope it reduced your confusion on the matter.If you didnt understant something plz ask me again

Comment: I would like to save the values from the firebase to an array. How to parse the values. I displayed in the html with the help of asyn. How can that be done

Comment: How can i get a single object instead of a list??