# How to create and access array of objects in firebase manually in angular?

Tags: html, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular-material

I have created list of multiple cards from array of objects stored in user.component.ts

user.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../service/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user',
  templateUrl: './user.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user.component.css']
})

export class UserComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public auth: AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  logout(){
    this.auth.logout();
  }



cards = [
    {
      title: 'Card Title 1',
      description: 'Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card content',
      buttonText: 'Button',
      img: 'https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(34).jpg'
    },
    {
      title: 'Card Title 2',
      description: 'Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card content',
      buttonText: 'Button',
      img: 'https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(34).jpg'
    },
    {
      title: 'Card Title 3',
      description: 'Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card content',
      buttonText: 'Button',
      img: 'https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(34).jpg'
    },
    {
      title: 'Card Title 4',
      description: 'Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card content',
      buttonText: 'Button',
      img: 'https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(34).jpg'
    },
    {
      title: 'Card Title 5',
      description: 'Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card content',
      buttonText: 'Button',
      img: 'https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(34).jpg'
    },
    {
      title: 'Card Title 6',
      description: 'Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card content',
      buttonText: 'Button',
      img: 'https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(34).jpg'
    },
    {
      title: 'Card Title 7',
      description: 'Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card content',
      buttonText: 'Button',
      img: 'https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(34).jpg'
    },
    {
      title: 'Card Title 8',
      description: 'Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card content',
      buttonText: 'Button',
      img: 'https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(34).jpg'
    },

  ];


}
```

Now how can i create a similar array of object in firebase database and retrieve it for list of cards creation in user.component.html

user.component.html

```
<select #myInput>
  <option selected></option>
  <option>Card Title 1</option>
</select>
 </span>
 <div class="container" >
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 mx-auto my-5" *ngFor="let card of cards | filterBy: 'title': myInput.value ">
      <mdb-card>
        <mdb-card-img [src]="card.img" alt="Card image cap">
        </mdb-card-img>
        <mdb-card-body>
          <mdb-card-title>
            <h4>{{card.title}}</h4>
          </mdb-card-title>

          <mdb-card-text>
            {{card.description}}
          </mdb-card-text>

          <button mdbBtn color="primary">{{card.buttonText}}</button>
        </mdb-card-body>
      </mdb-card>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

when data in the array is changed it should reflect in the list of cards.What to do?

Comment: Please see how to do CRUD operations in angular when using firebase: https://medium.com/factory-mind/angular-firebase-typescript-step-by-step-tutorial-2ef887fc7d71

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 4 Firebase Read data from database and display to browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45242925/angular-4-firebase-read-data-from-database-and-display-to-browser)

Answer (score -1):

1. Setup Firebase Account
2. Create Firebase Project
3. Enable FireStore
4. Add angularFire to your project (https://github.com/angular/angularfire)
5. Read about concepts of Collection Document, Query in firebase firestore
6. Develop some code
7. Debug
8. Develop more code
9. Google the issue you encounter
10. Fix the code
11. Done